# On Expedia, what do the letters mean next to cruise ship rooms and how can you view cruise critics ratings?

Tags: terminology, cruising, expedia

I'm trying to book a cruise via Expedia and...  well here's a screenshot:

[image]

What do the letters by the room descriptions mean? What does HH mean? Other letter combinations I'm seeing are H, F, G, DA, FF, etc, and I have no idea what any of them mean.

Also, it says stuff like "Cruise Critic Traveler Rating" but you can't click on it...  Seems kinda useless to mention it then. Is there a way the reviews can actually be read or is it just a black hole?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe both your questions can be answered by visiting [Cruise Critic](http://www.cruisecritic.com/reviews/). If I guessed correctly and you're on the Holland America, Amsterdam, say, then choosing [Amsterdam Deck 3: Lower Promenade Deck Plan](http://www.cruisecritic.com/amsterdam-deck-plans/dp/?shipID=173&deck=3), you'd see something like this:

[image]

Where HH is described as:

> Large Outside Stateroom (fully obstructed views) (HH)

An alternative view is available on [cruisedeckplans](https://www.cruisedeckplans.com/DP/deckplans/Amsterdam) and you can hover over the cabin codes to bring up a description.

The cabin reviews that expedia refers to should be on the cruise critic [reviews](http://www.cruisecritic.com/amsterdam-deck-plans/dp/cabin-reviews/) page.

[image]